# Align An Image Beside Chart

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, charts

I am trying to add a heatmap image beside the chart, which is as shown below. I want the heatmap image to be directly beside the chart. Has tried to set the chart height and image height to be the same but it does not work. Chart is generated dynamically out onto the tab panel.

[image]

Question: How to make sure **chart** height is **aligned** with the **heatmap image** height? In short, how to make them side by side each other?
Appreciate if someone can provide me help on this, thanks a lot!!

Regards,

Felicia

Comment: Have you try flexbox? - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to align them by applying display:inline-block to both.

For example, if your chart is tagged with id="chart" and heatmap is tagged with id="heatmap", your CSS should look the below:

```
#chart{display:inline-block}
#heatmap{display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#chart {
  display: inline-block; 
  float: left;
}
#heatmap {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: relative;
}
```